# Cannot create poolable connection to hsqldb

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hsqldb, applicationcontext

I am using `spring 3.2` and hibernate.

However, I am getting the following error:

```
    2008 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper  - Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (General error: database alias does not exist)
    Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:428)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:372)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:417)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:255)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631)
        at com.testPackage.PersonDaoImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$4fe1a0d7.save(<generated>)
        at com.testPackage.App.main(App.java:15)
    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1387)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1310)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1397)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:62)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.DefaultJpaDialect.beginTransaction(DefaultJpaDialect.java:71)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:60)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:378)
        ... 8 more
    Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:221)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:157)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:160)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1425)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:59)
        ... 11 more
    Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (General error: database alias does not exist)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:70)
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:292)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:214)
        ... 16 more
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: General error: database alias does not exist
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
        ... 21 more
    Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: General error: database alias does not exist
        at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.ClientConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
        ... 28 more

I have no idea why it cannot create a link to my `hsqldb`. At the moment I am running the hsqldb server and getting the following error output:
```

> ```
>   C:\user\testDb>java -cp C:/hsqldb-2.3.2/hsql
>     db-2.3.2/hsqldb/lib/hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.server.Server ûdatabase.0 file:testDB
>     ûdbname.0 testDB
>     [Server@c20e24]: [Thread[main,5,main]]: checkRunning(false) entered
>     [Server@c20e24]: [Thread[main,5,main]]: checkRunning(false) exited
>     [Server@c20e24]: Startup sequence initiated from main() method
>     [Server@c20e24]: Could not load properties from file
>     [Server@c20e24]: Using cli/default properties only
>     [Server@c20e24]: Initiating startup sequence...
>     [Server@c20e24]: Server socket opened successfully in 13 ms.
>     [Server@c20e24]: Database [index=0, id=0, db=file:test, alias=] opened sucessful
>     ly in 363 ms.
>     [Server@c20e24]: Startup sequence completed in 377 ms.
>     [Server@c20e24]: 2014-07-01 09:29:40.524 HSQLDB server 2.3.2 is online on port 9
>     001
>     [Server@c20e24]: To close normally, connect and execute SHUTDOWN SQL
>     [Server@c20e24]: From command line, use [Ctrl]+[C] to abort abruptly
>     [Server@c20e24]: [Thread[HSQLDB Connection @11b9fb1,5,HSQLDB Connections @c20e24
>     ]]: database alias=testdb does not exist
>     [Server@c20e24]: [Thread[HSQLDB Connection @691f36,5,HSQLDB Connections @c20e24]
>     ]: database alias=testdb does not exist
>     [Server@c20e24]: [Thread[HSQLDB Connection @12558d6,5,HSQLDB Connections @c20e24
>     ]]: database alias=testdb does not exist
>     [Server@c20e24]: [Thread[HSQLDB Connection @30e280,5,HSQLDB Connections @c20e24]
>     ]: database alias=testdb does not exist
>     [Server@c20e24]: [Thread[HSQLDB Connection @1ccb029,5,HSQLDB Connections @c20e24
>     ]]: database alias=testdb does not exist
>     [Server@c20e24]: [Thread[HSQLDB Connection @121cc40,5,HSQLDB Connections @c20e24
>     ]]: database alias=testdb does not exist
>     [Server@c20e24]: [Thread[HSQLDB Connection @1386000,5,HSQLDB Connections @c20e24
>     ]]: database alias=testdb does not exist
>     [Server@c20e24]: [Thread[HSQLDB Connection @147c5fc,5,HSQLDB Connections @c20e24
>     ]]: database alias=testdb does not exist
> ```

My `applicationContext.xml` looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">
    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <context:annotation-config />

    <bean id="personDao" class="com.testPackage.PersonDaoImpl" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/testDB" />
        <property name="username" value="sa" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
        <property name="initialSize" value="5" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="10" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="jpaData" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Any idea what is wrong with my connection?

**UPDATE**

I am running my connection from:

`java -cp C:/user/hsqldb-2.3.2/hsqldb-2.3.2/hsqldb/lib/hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.server.Server –database.0 file:testDB –dbname.0 testDB`

**UPDATE**

I started my server with:

`java -cp C:/user/hsqldb-2.3.2/hsqldb-2.3.2/hsqldb/lib/hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.server.Server --database.0 file:testDB --dbname.0 testDB`

However, I get this long exception(the error starts much earlier, because of that I am posting all of it):

```
1508 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  - HHH000319: Could not get database metadata
org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (General error: database alias does not exist)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:505)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1750)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:920)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:904)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:92)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:288)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1547)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1117)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:922)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.testPackage.App.main(App.java:11)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: General error: database alias does not exist
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: General error: database alias does not exist
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ClientConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    ... 35 more
1510 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  - HHH000299: Could not complete schema update
org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (General error: database alias does not exist)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:505)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1750)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:920)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:904)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:92)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:288)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1547)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1117)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:922)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.testPackage.App.main(App.java:11)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: General error: database alias does not exist
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: General error: database alias does not exist
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ClientConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    ... 35 more
1551 [main] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1bc82e7: defining beans [org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,personDao,dataSource,entityManagerFactory,transactionManager,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
1852 [main] WARN  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper  - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
1852 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper  - Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (General error: database alias does not exist)
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:428)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:372)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:417)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:255)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631)
    at com.testPackage.PersonDaoImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$4fe1a0d7.save(<generated>)
    at com.testPackage.App.main(App.java:15)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1387)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1310)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1397)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:62)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.DefaultJpaDialect.beginTransaction(DefaultJpaDialect.java:71)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:60)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:378)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:221)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1425)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:59)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (General error: database alias does not exist)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:292)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:214)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: General error: database alias does not exist
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: General error: database alias does not exist
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ClientConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    ... 28 more
```

**UPDATE**

after removing a space it seems ot work now!

Comment: Just to make entirely clear, are you starting the DB using `-database.0 file:testDB -dbname.0 testDB`? I am asking because there are some weird characters in the script you posted and also the HSQL log says `db=file:test, alias=` which clearly isn't what you want

Comment: @geoand Thx for your answer! Please just have a look at my update. I created a batch file for that.

Comment: Could you please try `--database.0 file:testDB--dbname.0 testDB` and let me know (take not of `--` instead of `-`)?

Comment: @geoand Thx I think I fixed it now. Just one last question, why should I use -- instead of -, what`s the reason behind that?

Comment: I found it in the documentation. I will add it as answer below for future readers to easily see.

Comment: @geoand do I also need in my `java -cp C:/user/hsqldb-2.3.2/hsqldb-2.3.2/hsqldb/lib/hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.util.DatabaseManagerSwing -user sa -url jdbc:hsqldb:database/testDB` double `--` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/running-chapt.html) part of the documentation you should be starting the database like this:

`java -cp C:/user/hsqldb-2.3.2/hsqldb-2.3.2/hsqldb/lib/hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.server.Server –-database.0 file:testDB –-dbname.0 testDB`

Note the use of `--` instead of `-`

Comment: Any further recommendations if also `java -cp C:/user/hsqldb-2.3.2/hsqldb-2.3.2/hsqldb/lib/hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.util.DatabaseManagerSwing -user sa -url jdbc:hsqldb:database/testDB` needs double `--`?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this as well as this problem: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52031333/6710870

When I didn't know that the config file way of setting `--dbname` or `-dbname` is `server.dbname.#=YOURDB`