# Empty DataBase when i use JPA2 with Hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee

I have an easy console application with JPA.

```
package com.concretepage.entity;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="farmer")
@NamedQuery(name = "farmer.getAll", query = "SELECT a from Farmer a")
public class Farmer {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name="village")

    private String village;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getVillage() {
        return village;
    }
    public void setVillage(String village) {
        this.village = village;
    }

}

package com.concretepage;

import com.concretepage.entity.Farmer;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
import java.util.List;

public class JPADemo {
    private static final EntityManagerFactory emFactory;
    static {
           emFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("com.concretepage");
    }
    public static EntityManager getEntityManager(){
        return emFactory.createEntityManager();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EntityManager em = getEntityManager();  
        em.getTransaction().begin();

        Farmer farmer = em.find(Farmer.class, 3);
        System.out.println(farmer);
        TypedQuery<Farmer> namedQuery = em.createNamedQuery("farmer.getAll",     Farmer.class);

        List<Farmer> farmers = namedQuery.getResultList();
        System.out.println(farmers);

        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}

<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="com.concretepage">
        <description>JPA Test</description>
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>com.concretepage.entity.Farmer</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>

            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/test"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Methods em.find(...) and namedQuery.getResultList() return true responses! Everythink'is OK :) 
But When i use this code in Web Service application:

```
@Stateless
public class TestService {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "MainDB")
    private EntityManager em;

    public Farmer add(Farmer farmer){
        farmer = em.merge(farmer);
        return farmer;
    }

    public Farmer get(Integer id){
        return em.find(Farmer.class, id);
    }

    public List<Farmer> getAll(){
        TypedQuery<Farmer> namedQuery = em.createNamedQuery("Farmer.getAll", Farmer.class);
        return namedQuery.getResultList();
    }
}
<persistence-unit name="MainDB" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>model.Farmer</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>

        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/test"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

If i use:

`<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
    or not use`

recieve Exeption: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing table
If i use:

`<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>`

recieve null response em.find(...) and namedQuery.getResultList(), but table and data are exist!
How i can use curent DB and data?

Comment: The property `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` is used to create database automatically.

Comment: I understand! But If i don't use hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto my connection get empty table without data!

Comment: `hbm2ddl` does not have to do anything with the data in the database AFAIK.

Comment: Why console application recieve some data, but web service not? Thr code is the same?

Comment: What error you get when you fetch data?

Comment: There're no errors if i use <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/> . Just an empty result of request database. If i delete <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/> then catch  java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: FARMER

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38415734/3094731) answer.